# OrderBy with variable TKey

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a list of FileInfo which I have to sort by different properties, e.g.

```
List<FileInfo> infoListOrdered = infoList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList();
```

Instead of writing the expression for every FileInfo property, would it be possible to pass the TKey as a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean? `TKey` is a type parameter... what would you want to be able to do?

Comment: For each property in `typeof(FileInfo).GetProperties()`, is it your intention to `OrderBy` that property? Why? What would you need all those ordered lists for?

Answer (score 1):

No, `TKey` is a type; the lamba `x=>x.CreationTime` is the value selector returning a value of type `TKey`. You can't select something based on its type only, for one there may be multiple property instances of that type in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on my (mis)understanding of the question. It gives `OrderBy` for each property `prop` that you might want to order by:

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> infoList = XXX; // your source to sort

    var orderByMeth = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var tFileInfo = typeof(FileInfo);
    foreach (var prop in tFileInfo.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        var tKey = prop.PropertyType;

        var xParam = Expression.Parameter(tFileInfo);
        var propBody = Expression.Property(xParam, prop.GetMethod);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propBody, xParam);
        var func = lambda.Compile();

        var orderByMethConstr = orderByMeth.MakeGenericMethod(tFileInfo, tKey);

        var result = orderByMethConstr.Invoke(null, new object[] { infoList, func, });
        var infoListOrdered = (IOrderedEnumerable<FileInfo>)result;

        // keep infoListOrdered; foreach through it to get that particular ordering
    }
}
```